# Is there a straightforward generalization of min(x,y) to positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, positivity, tropical-geometry

This is an open-ended question I have. Is there a function of two positive-semidefinite hermitian operators $\min(A,B)$ returning another positive-semidefinite Hermitian operator such that:

1. If A and B commute, the eigenvectors of $\min(A,B)$ should be the shared eigenvectors of A and B, with eigenvalues $\min (\lambda_A , \lambda_B)$ where $\lambda_A$ , $\lambda_B$ are the corresponding eigenvalues for A and B.
2. When A and B do not necessarily commute, $A - \min(A,B)$ and $B - \min(A,B)$ should always be positive semidefinite, so that both A and B are greater than $\min(A,B)$ in the Löwner order.

If yes, is there a straightforward proof or construction of such a function? If not, is there any theorem limiting what properties such a function can have?

Now, these two axioms by themselves are fairly weak. You can easily find a trivial but not so powerful example by defining $\min(A,B)$ as being defined by axiom 1) if the two operators exactly commute and $\min (\lambda^{\min}_A , \lambda^{\min}_B) I$ otherwise, where $\lambda^{\min}_A$, $ \lambda^{\min}_B$ are the smallest eigenvalues of A and B.

So I'll reformulate the question: is there a *reasonable* such function with more useful properties?

Possible other useful properties that it could have (optional, should satisfy as many of them as possible):

3. Min should be associative and commutative.
4. It should distribute over addition if possible, like in the tropical semiring for real numbers (this is most likely way too strong of a condition but I would be happy to be proven wrong).
5. Translation invariance: $\min(A + C,B + C) = \min(A,B) + C$ at least when C commutes with A and B (in particular when C is a multiple of the identity matrix). This is somewhat weaker than 4)
6. $\min(A,B)$ should ideally be continuous in A and B.
7. the smallest eigenvalue of $\min(A,B)$ should not be "too much smaller" than the smallest eigenvalues of A and B (a strong version of this with equality would follow from 5 and positive definiteness).

Comment: This is an idea for defining $\max$ on positive-definite Hermitian matrices, but if it does work it might be able to be modified into defining $\min$ on positive semi-definite Hermitian matrices. For positive real numbers $x$ and $y$, it's a well-known fact that $\lim_{a \to \infty} (x^a + y^a)^{1/a} = \max\{x,y\}$. These operations all make sense for positive-definite Hermitian matrices, and this should have the right behavior for commuting matrices.

Comment: @JamesHanson The same expression converges to $\min\{x,y\}$ for $a \to -\infty$ (but if the matrices are only semidefinite then the negative exponents are a problem).

Comment: I was interested in this question a few years ago. Then I found that the set of Hermitian matrices $C$ such that $C\le A$ and $C\le B$ does not admit a largest element ; unless $A$ and $B$ commutte of course.

Comment: Right. The thing with this question is that I'm interested in a tropical semiring-like structure on matrices, so I don't need uniqueness for maximal elements.

Right now, a "good enough" choice seems to be  $\min(x,y) := \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \log_h(h^x + h^y)$, due to the ease of proving various properties, particularly translation invariance.

Comment: Consider$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2&1-i\\ 1+i&2\end{pmatrix},\ B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&3\end{pmatrix}$$ For the maximum either $$M=\lim_{n\to\infty}(A^n+B^n)^{1/n}\ \text{or}\ M=\lim_{h\to\infty}\log(e^{hA}+e^{hB})/h$$$$\implies M= \frac12\begin{pmatrix}5+\sqrt{2}&(1-i)+(-1)^{3/4}\\ (1+i)-(-1)^{1/4}& 5+\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$For the minimum either$$m=\lim_{n\to-\infty}(A^n+B^n)^{1/n}\ \text{or}\ m=\lim_{h\to-\infty}\log(e^{hA}+e^{hB})/h$$ $$\implies m=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}3-\sqrt{2}& (1-i)+(-1)^{3/4} \\ (1+i)-(-1)^{1/4}&3-\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$Then$$A,B,M,m,A+B-m>0\ \text{but}\ A+B-M\ngeq0$$

Comment: The inequalities I forgot to check are weirder! It turns out $$M>B>m\ \text{ and }\ M\geq A \geq m\ \text{ but }\ M \not > A \not > m$$

Comment: A new development after doing some reading: there is a partial ordering of matrices called the star order, which happens to satisfy:
1) that it is a min (meet) semilattice, and 
2) For positive semidefinite matrices, $A <^* B$ implies $A <^L B$ where the latter is the usual Löwner order. But of course it may be too coarse to be useful

Comment: More generally, if we have a min function which is commutative, associative, and idempotent (and all of these are properties that I want), then it necessarily induces a (meet-semilattice) partial order on matrices. If I add condition 2), then that is equivalent to stating that said ordering implies the Löwner order. It might be worth checking that the orders induced by our min functions are valid preorders

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is the kind of answer that you were looking for, but (hat tip [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2548062)) the preprint

> Nikolas Stott, *Maximal lower bounds in the Löwner order* [[arXiv:1612.05664]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.05664)

seems to have a detailed discussion of *maximal lower bounds* of two symmetric matrices with respect to the [Löwner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), which is precisely the partial order generated by the cone of positive semi-definite matrices. The conclusion seems to be that maximal lower bounds are generally non-unique (in a partial order a strict maximum may not exist due to incomparable elements), but can be usefully parametrized. Whether there could be a useful way to pick a preferred maximal lower bound by a formula, I can't say.

Comment: Ah, this definitely adds a lot of information about criterion 2) at least, which is very useful.